# Alternatives to APFS which keeps corrupting itself?

Tags: macos, mojave, apfs, hfs+

Macos mojave locked up, forcing me to reboot. I was then presented with the prohibitory symbol indicating that the OS can no longer load. It was caused by APFS being corrupted, confirmed by disk utility in recovery mode. Disk utility did nothing to repair the problem.

I reinstalled the OS and restored everything from a backup. One day later macos locked up again, and I once again had to reboot. It now stops booting after filling the progress bar while loading the OS. APFS has once again managed to corrupt itself, evident both when staring in verbose mode and when running disk utility in recovery mode. A checksum for some object is invalid. Disk utility once again makes no attempt to actually fix anything and I have found no evidence of any other APFS tools from apple for this purpose.

I'm not resizing partitions or anything advanced when it happens, just using Firefox and getting a beach ball.

I can't think of any other solution to the situation other than to get rid of APFS:

- Reinstalling the OS onto an HFS+ partition. I tried this -- the installer ignores the existing file system and created APFS anyway.
- Install an older version of the OS on HFS+
- Use some hack to force mojave onto HFS+
- Use a different OS

The SSD is a 500 GB, less than a year old Samsung 860 EVO that boots Windows 10 with seemingly no problems so the hardware does not seem to be the problem.

Are there any other obvious options that I have missed in my list? (buying new hardware because the file system is useless doesn't qualify)

Comment: Different question, same requirement. Yes it can be done, but it will fight you all the way. I'd investigate what's wrong with the drive as it stands.

Comment: @Tetsujin Different question, but duplicate question. Got it 

Comment: Andreas - I often forget I have "close-hammer" abilities for certain topics because of my reputation on this stack - 'one vote to close, gold badge' - so I thought I'd best add some explanation. Being a dupe doesn't diminish the question, it just gives more potential searchers a linked path to their goal. If there's a specific reason it shouldn't be marked as a dupe, then editing your question will drop it to a review queue for reopening. Wish you luck :)